# For boost io_service, is only-one thread blocked on epoll_wait?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost-asio

I read the source code of Boost ASIO, and I wanna find out it is only one thread for it to call epoll_wait(Of course,if I use epoll reactor).
I wanna find its solution about more than one thread to call epoll_wait, this may cause different threads doing the read for the same socket at the same time .
I read some key codes as follows:

```
// Prepare to execute first handler from queue.
      operation* o = op_queue_.front();
      op_queue_.pop();
      bool more_handlers = (!op_queue_.empty());

      if (o == &task_operation_)
      {
        task_interrupted_ = more_handlers;

        if (more_handlers && !one_thread_)
          wakeup_event_.unlock_and_signal_one(lock);
        else
          lock.unlock();

        task_cleanup on_exit = { this, &lock, &this_thread };
        (void)on_exit;

        // Run the task. May throw an exception. Only block if the operation
        // queue is empty and we're not polling, otherwise we want to return
        // as soon as possible.
        task_->run(!more_handlers, this_thread.private_op_queue);
      }
```

task_ is epoll reactor and it will call epoll_wait in the run, 
I guess it may only one thread to call it because only one "task_operation_" in the op_queue_, am I right ?
If I wanna use epoll in multi-threading, or I may use "EPOLLONESHOT" so that it can ensure that one thread handle one socket at one time.

Comment: There's nothing special you need to do. Unless you think you know better how to multithread on your platform than the ASIO developers, don't mess with it. It's already the best design they were able to come up with.

Answer (score 3):

Only a single thread will invoke `epoll_wait`.  Once the thread receives event notifications for descriptors, it will demultiplex the descriptors to all threads running the `io_service`.  Per the [Platform-Specific Implementation Notes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html):

> Threads:
>
> - Demultiplexing using `epoll` is performed in one of the threads that calls `io_service::run()`, `io_service::run_one()`, `io_service::poll()` or `io_service::poll_one()`.

A single descriptor will be processed by a single thread that will perform the I/O. Hence, when using asynchronous operations, I/O will not be performed concurrently for a given socket.

Answer (score 2):

- First case, is when you are using a single instance of `io_service` and calling `io_service::run` method from multiple threads.

Lets see the `schduler::run` function (simplified):

```
std::size_t scheduler::run(asio::error_code& ec)
{
  mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);

  std::size_t n = 0;
  for (; do_run_one(lock, this_thread, ec); lock.lock())
    if (n != (std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max)())
      ++n;
  return n;
}
```

So, with the lock held, it calls the `do_run_one` method, which is something like:

```
std::size_t scheduler::do_run_one(mutex::scoped_lock& lock,
    scheduler::thread_info& this_thread,
    const asio::error_code& ec)
{
  while (!stopped_)
  {
    if (!op_queue_.empty())
    {
      // Prepare to execute first handler from queue.
      operation* o = op_queue_.front();
      op_queue_.pop();
      bool more_handlers = (!op_queue_.empty());

      if (o == &task_operation_)
      {
        task_interrupted_ = more_handlers;

        if (more_handlers && !one_thread_)
          wakeup_event_.unlock_and_signal_one(lock);
        else
          lock.unlock();

        task_cleanup on_exit = { this, &lock, &this_thread };
        (void)on_exit;

        task_->run(!more_handlers, this_thread.private_op_queue);
      }
      else
      {
        //......
      }
    }
    else
    {
      wakeup_event_.clear(lock);
      wakeup_event_.wait(lock);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The interesting part of the code sre these lines:

```
if (more_handlers && !one_thread_)
  wakeup_event_.unlock_and_signal_one(lock);
else
  lock.unlock();
```

The case we are discussing now is the one with multiple threads, so the first condition will satisfy (assuming we have quite a number of pending tasks in op_queue_).

What `wakeup_event_.unlock_and_signal_one` ends up doing is release/unlock the `lock` and notify one of threads who is waiting on a conditional wait. So, with this, atleast one another thread (whoever gets the lock) can call `do_run_one` now.

The `task_` in your case is `epoll_reactor` as you have said. And, in it's `run` method it calls `epoll_wait` (not holding the `lock_` of `scheduler`).

The interesting thing here is what it does when it iterates over all the ready descriptors that `epoll_wait` returned. It pushes them back in the operational queue it received as reference in the argument. The operations pushed now have the run time type of `descriptor_state` instead of `task_operation_`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_events; ++i)
  {
    void* ptr = events[i].data.ptr;
    if (ptr == &interrupter_)
    {
      // don't call work_started() here. This still allows the scheduler to
      // stop if the only remaining operations are descriptor operations.
      descriptor_state* descriptor_data = static_cast<descriptor_state*>(ptr);
      descriptor_data->set_ready_events(events[i].events);
      ops.push(descriptor_data);
    }
  }
```

So, in the next iteration of the while loop inside `scheduler::do_run_one`, for the completed tasks, it will hit the `else` branch (which I elided in my paste earlier):

```
     else
      {
        std::size_t task_result = o->task_result_;

        if (more_handlers && !one_thread_)
          wake_one_thread_and_unlock(lock);
        else
          lock.unlock();

        // Ensure the count of outstanding work is decremented on block exit.
        work_cleanup on_exit = { this, &lock, &this_thread };
        (void)on_exit;

        // Complete the operation. May throw an exception. Deletes the object.
        o->complete(this, ec, task_result);

        return 1;
      }
```

Which call the `complete` function pointer which inturn probably will call the user passed handle to the `async_read` or `async_write` API.

- Second case, is where you create a pool of `io_service` objects and call its `run` method on 1 or more threads i.e the mapping between `io_service` and `thread` could be 1:1 or 1:N as may suit your application. This way you can assign an `io_service` object to a `soucket` object in round robin fashion.

Now, coming to your question:

> If I wanna use epoll in multi-threading, or I may use "EPOLLONESHOT"
>   so that it can ensure that one thread handle one socket at one time.

If I understood this correctly, you want to handle all the events to a socket using 1 thread ? I think this is possible by following approach number 2, i.e to create a pool of `io_service` objects and map it to 1 thread. This way you can be sure that all the activity on a particular socket will be addressed by only one thread i.e the thread on which that `io_service:run`.

You do not have to worry about setting `EPOLLONESHOT` in the above case.

I am not so sure about getting the same behaviour using the first approach, which is multiple thread and 1 `io_service`.

But, if you are not using threads at all i.e your `io_service` runs on single thread, then you don't have to worry about all this, after all the purpose of asio is to abstract all these stuff.

Comment: Thank you for writing so much. It helps me a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: @NeoLiu  Just as a general information on stackoverflow - If you find any answer really helpful to your asked question, you should 'accept' it by clicking the 'check' sign below the counter (top-right of the answer). I see you have not accepted any answer till now and since you know about it now you can start accepting them :)